# Laravel 5.1 - Error al crear/usar facade personalizado

Tags: laravel-5

Cree una clase, añadí el *Service Provider* y probe a llamar un método, por ejemplo, "test()" y funciono. Seguidamente creo un *facade* en "app/Facades/MiClase.php":

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MyClase extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        //return 'mc';
        //return 'MC';
        return 'mC';
    }

} //class
```

*Comentadas otras pruebas para devolver el nombre del facade a usar.*..

En "config/app.php", en el array "aliases" tengo:

```
'MC' => App\Facades\MyClase::class,
```

Probe a llamarlo en "routes.php":

```
Route::get( 'mc-facade', function() {
    MC::test();
});
```

y en un controlador...

Tengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> FatalThrowableError in Facade.php line 216: Fatal error: Call to
>   undefined method App\Facades\MiClase::test()

*Probando en local con Xampp / Windows.*

Comment: Intenta correr los comandos artisan cache:clear y luego artisan config:cache y luego prueba.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta bindearlo en el provider

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('mC', 'App\Facades\MyClase ' );
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres decir bindear el facade?

Comment: Parece que el tema si puede estar en el provider. Sólo que si bindeas el facade no funciona, hay que usar el bindeo como indicas pero a la clase original, es decir: $this->app->bind( 'mC', 'App\Helpers\MyClase ' );